# Datagrid in WPF and sql datatable vs other methods

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Here is what i tried to do.. I want to provide an in place editing of products within a datagrid. Firstly i wrapped into a ObservableCollection a `List<Product>` and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface for each POCO. Undoing changes and tracking what has changed in order to commit seems hard and i had lots of problems.. Also i feel that creating so many event handlers for every single poco when a property changed is not good strange...
So i am asking does DataTable solve these problems ?    Even it solves what about validation ?It doesnt know anything about the POCO....  Are any other better solutions for this ??

Comment: Are you working with an `ObservableCollection<List<Product>>` or `ObservableCollection<Product>`?

Comment: the first ,to the list ofcource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property change handlers aren't that bad. Here's an example:

```
// Hook up a CollectionChanged event
ProductCollection.CollectionChanged += ProductCollection_Changed;

// In the Collection Changed event, hook up a PropertyChanged event
void ProductCollection_Changed(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Product item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += Product.PropertyChanged;
    }

    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Product item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= Product.PropertyChanged;
    }
}

// In the Product property changed event, do something.
// Usually I only use this for raising the CollectionChanged event when
// a property of an object inside a collection changes.
void Product_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Personally, I would prefer to have each `Product` track it's own changes, instead of tracking them in the ViewModel. When a product first gets created, keep a copy of the original data, and provide something like a `UndoChanges()` method that simply reloads the original data.

To track changes on individual properties, I would do that in the `set` method of each `Product` property. This is because the `PropertyChanged` event can be raised manually, and doesn't necessarily mean that the property has changed.

```
private int _someValue;
public int SomeValue
{
    get { return _someValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _someValue)
        {
            // Track what's changed here. 
            // How you do it is based on what you want to track
            if (!ChangedProperties.Keys.Contains("SomeValue"))
            {
                ChangedProperties.Add(
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("SomeValue", _someValue));
            }

            _someValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SomeValue");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well at your first sample that would work for new items only. What about existing products  ? Should i iterate each product at the begining ?

Comment: @Parhs Providing you hook up the `CollectionChanged` event prior to populating the `ObservableCollection`, the first example will run for your initial items too. If not, you'll have to manually loop through the items after the initial load and hook up their `PropertyChanged` events in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

DataTable do solve a few things...

1. When you are not sure how many columns you are going to have.
2. When there are frequent edits, the edits take place onto the data table  and if the data table has constraints then they will error out for invalid entries. So some level of validation and data integrity is maintained.
3. Being queryable, the data tables produce faster results with sorting and filtering with their DefaultView i.e. `DataView`.

Having said that ...

1. Frequent updates are better achieved by observable collection with each item having  implemented `INotifypropertyChanged`.
2. Validations using `Bindings` are easily achievable.
3. Datagrid does provide some more features for object model of collections than data tables.

So ultimately its your choice. However I dont mind observable collections and INotifyPropertyChanged notifications as they seem to get the best out of WPF DataGrid... styling and performance wise.

Comment: I want to achieve bulk edit. However using notifications i should track which rows have changed , so no other solution for this ?  With datatable it is more difficult to do validations etc ?

Comment: Thats what I said, I still think `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` is good. They will offer you frequent edits and binding based validations.

Comment: i dont know why i cant find any sample over the internet except datatable specific. Knowing which rows have changed seems ok and easy but it seems too complex to not create an update query for full poco.